# Why single quote is ignored in case expression?

Tags: racket, quote

```
(case 'x
   [(x) "ex"]
   [('x) "quoted ex"])
```

I thought the output would be `"quoted ex"`, but it is `"ex"` actually. Why `'x` match `x` but not `'x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, `(x)` is *already* quoted, from the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/case.html) (emphasis mine):

> The selected clause is the first one with a *datum* whose **`quoted`** form is `equal?` to the result of `val-expr`.

Therefore, `('x)` is doubly-quoted. If you wanted to match the second case, something like this would be necessary:

```
(case ''x
  [(x) "ex"]
  [('x) "quoted ex"])

=> "quoted ex"
```

To put it another way, the first condition in your code is testing if `(equal? 'x 'x)` and the second one tests `(equal? 'x ''x)`, clearly only the first one matches.